# Bash programming - how to transfer the content of variables to another bash file

Tags: bash

I have 4 entries stored in a variable called TEMP_BLA_BLA like this:

12345,67890
44444,55555

Notes:

- Those are stored in 2 lines.
- They are also stored on disk in a file, which can be accessed via variable DISK_BLA_BLA (to provide a name).

Now I would like to transfer them to another bash file:

```
    sh calc_new_file.sh $1 $2 $3 $4
```

What do I have to do before I can pass those to calc_new_file.sh as commas and new line are preventing me from doing so?

Tia

Comment: Is the variable TEMP_BLA_BLA is a bash variable like `TEMP_BLA_BLA=12345,647890\n44444,55555` ? Is $DISK_BLA_BLA a bash variable which contains the path to the file contains the `$TEMP_BLA_BLA` ? What are `$1 $2 ...` in your example? In the title you ask as there are 2 bash files, is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses sed:

```
sh calc_new_file $(echo $TEMP_BLA_BLA | sed 's/,/ /g')
```

This uses `sed` to replace any commas with spaces.  We don't need to replace newlines with spaces because, for purposes of word-splitting, bash treats them the same as spaces.

`s/,/ /g` is a `sed` substitute command.  `s/,/ /` would replace the first comma with a space.  `s/,/ /g` replaces every comma with a space.

If you have a file instead of a variable:

```
sh calc_new_file $(cat DISK_BLA_BLA | sed 's/,/ /g')
```

Answer (score 0):

Word splitting is controlled by the `$IFS` variable. To make variables split into seperate arguments based on line feeds and commas, you can use:

```
IFS=',
'
sh calc_new_file.sh $TEMP_BLA_BLA
```